# Hiding div with no image

Tags: jquery

I have a list of containers, some with photos and others without. I need to find the `.thumbnail` div's without images, and hide their containers from the rendered view. I have the following, but can't target the empty thumbnail div correctly:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                     <h4 class="">Title of story</h4>
 <a href=""><img src="" class="fb"></a>

                    <img src="" class="tw">
                    </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <img src="" alt="..." class="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                     <h4 class="">Title of story</h4>
 <a href=""><img src="" class="fb"></a>

                    <img src="" class="tw">
                    </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="..." class="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
if($(".thumbnail").length() == ''){
    $(".thumbnail").find('.col-md-3').remove();
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/wzdrg6ob/1/)**

Comment: You have a couple orphaned `</a>` and `</p>` tags. Where are the *empty* `.thumbnail` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not able to understand your question properly,but if you are hiding divs with `<img>` without any source,then maybe this would help.

```
$(".thumbnail").find("img[src='']").parent().hide();
```

Please note: i have used parent() because i dont know exactly which div to hide.

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute [**not equal**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) selector

```js
$('.thumbnail:not(:has(img[src!=""]))').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                     <h4 class="">Title of story</h4>
 <a href=""><img src="" class="fb"></a>

                    <img src="" class="tw">
                    </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <img src="" alt="..." class="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                     <h4 class="">Title of story</h4>
 <a href=""><img src="" class="fb"></a>

                    <img src="" class="tw">
                    </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="..." class="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```